# Counterexample to $m(B\setminus A) = m(B) - m(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I just proved the following theorem for my measure theory course (note that $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$)

> Prove that if $A \subset B$ and $m(A)$ is finite, then $m(B\setminus A) = m(B) - m(A)$.

I found this to be a pretty straight forward proof since we can write $B = (B\setminus A) \cup (B \cap A) = (B\setminus A) \cup A$, where $A = B \cap A$ since $A \subset B$. However, I began to question if we could find a counterexample to this statement if $m(A)$ is *not* finite? Heres what I thought of:

> Let $A:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x\}$ and $B := \mathbb{R}$. Therefore since $A \subset B$ and $m(A) = \infty$, we have that $m(B\setminus A) = \infty - \infty$.

Is this correct? Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: If $m(A)$ is infinite, then this is not untrue, this just doesn't make sense.

Comment: What does it even mean to perform arithmetic with infinities?  What sensible meaning could be given to $\infty-\infty$?

Comment: What is always true is that if $B\subset A$ are measurable, then $m(A) = m(B) + m (A\setminus B) \in \mathbb{R}_+\cup \{\infty\}$. But the substraction does not make sense.

Comment: @DIdier_ - So would it be better to say for a counterexample that if $m(A)$ is infinite, then the subtraction is not defined?

Comment: Yes. One can extend addition to $\mathbb{R}_+\cup \{\infty\}$ in a consistent way, but it becomes a set that has no real algebraic structure, so opposite number does not make sense, hence substraction neither. In my own opinion, I find it better to never use the minus sign when doing measure theory.

Comment: @DIdier_ -  just talked to my  professor and he said that it is not enough just to say "it does not make sense" - and that I should think more about disjoint sets for a counterexample? Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Well, if $A$ and $B$ are measurable and $B\subset A$, then $A = (A \setminus B) \cup B$ is a disjoint union of measurable sets so the property of a measure assures $m(A) = m(A\setminus B) + m(B)$. I don't get the point of your professor

Comment: @DIdier_ - Turns out he made a mistake, as you mentioned! Thank you for your time today.